# Error-188 'System.Drawing.Image' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' in vb.net

Tags: image, data-binding

I am trying to show an image on the screen. The image is already been saved in the database in the form of `bytes[]`.

This `bytes[]` is retrieved into a dataset but when I try to show this `bytes[]` data into a `drawing.image` and then passing this to the `photo.source` this error is throwing

> system.drawing.image'cannot be converted into system.windows.media.imagesource!

Can anyone help me out

Comment: Hi! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for hints on improving your question. As it is several things are left unclear. For example which language you're programming in or what you've already tried.

Comment: @JakobRunge Thank you, Im using .net coding. The problem is the image is not getting converted to a proper bytes[] which is long raw